# Meltano execution output in variable

Tags: meltano

I am trying to check if meltano execution completed successfully or if there is any error by using following method

output=$(meltano run tap-csv target-postgres)

if echo grep -q "ERROR=0" logfile.txt  ; then
echo $outputcmdseed
echo "meltano run tap-csv target-postgres execution completed successfully.."

else
echo "meltano run tap-csv target-postgres   failed"

fi

but i am not getting value of console log in output variable.

Is there any way to achive this?

I need the output of colsole log in output variable